# Can bash strict mode be used in a makefile?

Tags: bash, makefile

You can explicitly set the shell used by the makefile with:

```
SHELL := /bin/bash
```

Will following this `#!/bin/bash` substitute with the rest of the `bash strict mode` header work?

```
set -euo pipefail
IFS=$'\n\t'
```

http://redsymbol.net/articles/unofficial-bash-strict-mode/

Comment: Have you tried it?

Answer (score 1):

Each line in a make rule is a new subshell, so no the header doesn't directly carry over.

One option is to prefix each line of your make rule:

```
my-rule:
    set -euo pipefail; \
    IFS=$'\n\t'; \
    <the rest of your line>
```

Another option is to use bash strict mode in a shell script that your make rule just calls:

```
my-rule:
    ./my-script-with-bash-strict-mode.sh
```

Another option is to wrap all of your rules beneath one with that header.  That assumes you only have one entry point into your makefile.

```
my-top-level-rule:
    set -euo pipefail; \
    IFS=$'\n\t'; \
    ${MAKE} <my-other-rule>
```

Comment: In a newer GNU Make, another option is to use [.ONESHELL](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/One-Shell.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can start your Makefile with something like

```
SHELL := bash
.SHELLFLAGS := -eu -o pipefail -c
```

This takes care of `set -euo pipefail`.

I haven't found a way to set `IFS` for every shell command. Normal environment variables can be set with

```
export MY_VAR := my-val
```

and are then available in every shell, but I couldn't get this to work with `IFS`.